# Python dict achieve java higherKey() function to find value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

Here is a dict `level = {1.4:'A',2.5:'B',3.5:'C'}`

I wanna match `score = 1.6` to `level` and return the value of `'B'`; it return the value of the key which is larger than `score` but the smallest.

In java I do it by the function:

```
level.get(level.higherKey(score));
```

But what to do in python? I suppose python could achieve it elegant.

Comment: `level.get(math.ceil(score))` ?

Comment: What do you mean by "match"?

Comment: @SelçukGülcan Maybe my demo is  inappropriate, I have modified it.

Comment: @U9-Forward it return the value of the key which is larger than score but the smallest.

Comment: @JoeKevin I do not think it can be achieved with `O(1)` time complexity. You may need a specialized data structure.

Comment: Python dicts are like `HashMap`, not `TreeMap`. Order isn't involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need this:

```
level = {1.4: 'A', 2.5: 'B', 3.5: 'C'}
score = 1.6

print(level.get(min((k for k in level if score <= k), default=None)))    
# B
```

Using `min` on generator expression guarantees that it returns the smallest key that is greater than `score`.

Comment: It's wrong to use `next`? `next` works for me in pandas.

Comment: `next` finds first key satisfying condition. Example for `score = 1.6` and `level = {3.5: 'C', 2.5: 'B', 1.4: 'A'}`, the answer would be different. `min` looks over all keys and returns the smallest one satisfying the criteria.

Answer (score 1):

```
try:
    print(level[min(filter(lambda x: x > score, level))])
except ValueError:
    print("No match")
```

This prints the value of the minimum key greater than `score`. If there isn't one it prints 'No match'.

Answer (score 0):

```
print(level[min([i for i in level.keys() if i > score])])
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using an ordered dictionary to return the next greater value?

```
def higherKey(level, value):
    for elem in collections.OrderedDict(sorted(level.items(), key=lambda t: t)):
        if elem > value:
            return level[elem]
```

Comment: OrderedDict has no use here, `for elem in sorted(level.keys()):` will do the same thing.